# How to convert 6 digit decimal to date format (SQL)

Tags: sql, date, format

Would like to convert 6 digit decimal e.g. 310322 (ddmmyy) to Date Format to 2022-03-31?

Thank you.

Comment: Which language? Probably you will have a date constructor which will take year, month, day. Just split the string into 3 groups of two, convert to integer, and add 2000 to year. Or you should add more information (and your code attempts) here.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi hi, I m looking for SQL language specifically for Impala. Thanks.

Comment: So, add the relative tag to the question. Nobody can read all questions (and most of them we cannot answer). So we filter questions by tag. Your have just a single generic tag, so do not expect many viewers (and so solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what language you are using, I will share in python.
You just have to separate the elements by positions and convert in the format that you want to use, in this case as you can see i added the timezone UTC for better format:

```
Decimal_value = 310322
Year = int(decimal_value[4:5])
month = int(decimal_value[2:3])
day = int(decimal_value[0:1])

Date_format = datetime(day, month, year).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Impala you have to convert it into a timestamp and then do to_date

```
 select to_date(to_timestamp('310322', 'DDMMYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD');
```